# Jquery method autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am new to Jquery and am facing problems implemting this method autocomplete:
from [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rdworth/ebduf/) URL.

I get this error

```
:Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'
```

in the javascript part of my code:

Code:
**index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
    body{font:62.5% Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;}
</style>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>
    <input id="autocomplete"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Code: **function.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( req, resp ) {
      $.post( "/echo/json/", {
          json: '["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]',
          delay: 1
      }, function(data) {
        resp( data );
      }, "JSON" );
  }
 });
});
```

Question: Am I missing out any important files or external files/libraries that I need to link to ?

Comment: On your link everything's ok, no error message

Comment: 'Jquery ui is not included in the script.

Comment: Why did you remove the jsfiddle link from your question?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the script tag for jquery-ui. Add this and it should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

(Hint: View the source of the output frame from your jsfiddle link and compare it to yours.)

Comment: Hi Russell, I insert that line, but it still does not work, am I missing out something else

Comment: @SamuelTang: Make sure you use a version of jQuery UI that works with your version of jQuery. Usually the latest one: http://jqueryui.com/download/.